# Error not being obtained in file

Tags: linux

Probably a naive question but I am stuck.

I have a shell script `file.sh` which contains a simple command(I don't have `python` installed)

`echo $PATH && cd /home/akash/repos/dhvani/ && echo $PWD && python main.py`

When I run it as `sh file.sh > /tmp/out`. I get the the portions of `echo` in the `/tmp/out` but not the error. I don't have `python` installed so I must get error like `python: not found` in the file as well. But I only get that in the terminal.

Can anyone explain a way how can I log this error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `stderr` as well as `stdout` go to the file, do this:

```
sh file.sh > /tmp/out 2>&1
```